# Use fn_output_signature instead stop problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

My Input;

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models\my_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite --pipeline_config_path=models\my_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite\pipeline.config
```

Output;

prnt.sc/104ecjv

My learning stopped at this stage and is not moving.

My Reference;
https://github.com/armaanpriyadarshan/Training-a-Custom-TensorFlow-2.x-Object-Detector Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and wasted many hours on this. Here is how i solved it

1. Make sure you don't have any negetive values of width, height in your csv
2. Do some sanity checks on your generated csv file.
3. If there are no proper checks in the scripts then tf_records.records has no information (0kb)
4. In one of my case, I was installing package using pip and the was resetting the gpu allocated in google colab.

Also refer below links.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9106

https://bleepcoder.com/models/627797941/tensorflow-python-framework-errors-impl-invalidargumenterror_8595